# Mysql Group same value together and show all rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table have city column

I want to group all same city together (GROUP BY will only show 1 rows, but I want all rows)

ex.

```
LA
New York
LA
LA
New York

output
New York
New York
LA
LA
LA
```

Comment: Do you mean `Order by` ??

Comment: ^ Aside from that, you can also select DISTINCT to not have duplicate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need order by instead of group by

```
select * from table order by city
```

There might be another issue when you have city names mixed with lower and upper case and it will not order properly in that case so you need to format the order by as

```
select upper(city) from test
order by lower(city);
```

or

```
select city from test
order by lower(city);
```

Comment: some of city in Chinese, and I found the order not very accuracy

Comment: can you provide some sample data ?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`

Comment: I have try order by but not very accuracy, some of city in this column are in Chinese

Answer (score 1):

`order by` will helps you

```
select * from tablename order by city
```

---

Try with length of the string

```
select * from cityname order by CHAR_LENGTH(city) desc
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f9f35/4)

Answer (score 0):

Try `ORDER BY` as other answers suggest (the one from Abhik seems very complete)

Aside from that If you want to know how many cities of each type do you have you can do something like this:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(city) FROM table GROUP BY city ORDER BY city
```

This query will return

> LA | 3
>
> New York | 2

This will give you a better way to count your cities (if you want to do something like this)